# Why is didFindPlacemark never hit?

Tags: iphone, mkreversegeocoder

I am struggling with getting my MKReverseGeocoder to actually finish. This is what I do:

```
// reverse geocode the user location
geocoder = [[[MKReverseGeocoder alloc] initWithCoordinate:mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate] autorelease];
geocoder.delegate = self;
[geocoder start];
```

The userLocation coordinate IS valid, I know that. I have didFindPlacemark and didFailWithError, and neither of those are hit...
Either I have the delegate set up wrong or I have no idea...Here's the header:

```
@interface E_85AppDelegate : UIViewController <UIApplicationDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate, MKReverseGeocoderDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate>
{   
    IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
    IBOutlet UITabBarController* tabBarController;
    IBOutlet MKMapView*   mapView;
    IBOutlet MKReverseGeocoder* geocoder;
        // other class members...
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like your declarations are correct. Show your code for the delegate methods. That last time I had something like this happen, I had the delegate method header wrong. Those darn descriptive Objective-C naming conventions ;)

Comment: Yeah, the method header was fine. It was frustrating especially since I had it working fine at one point. Thanks for the reply though :).

Answer (score 1):

Evidently my understanding of autorelease is not very good. It releases the geocoder before didFindPlacemark is ever sent the message.